# Can't read serial port in linux

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

I need to learn how to read and write serial port. For testing purposes I connect transmit line to receive line and check signal behaviour by oscilloscope. I can see that write is OK: 1 data byte is transferred from Tx to Rx. But function `read(fd, &rcv_val, 1)` returns -1.

Was used different ports: "/dev/ttyUSB0", "/dev/ttyS5".

I saw similar questions on this site, but its doesn't help me to solve a problem.

Code:

```
int res = 0;
int fd; /* File descriptor for the port */
int snd_val, rcv_val;

fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
if (fd == -1){//Could not open the port.
    fprintf(stderr, "open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyUSB0 - %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return fd;
}

speed_t baud = B38400;
struct termios settings;
tcgetattr(fd, &settings);
cfsetispeed(&settings, baud); // baud rate
cfsetospeed(&settings, baud); // baud rate
settings.c_cflag &= ~PARENB; // no parity
settings.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB; // 1 stop bit
settings.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
settings.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
settings.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
settings.c_cflag |= (CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD);
tcflush(fd, TCOFLUSH | TCIFLUSH);
tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &settings);// apply the settings

snd_val = 0xA5;
write(fd, &snd_val, 1);
if (res < 0){
    printf("Err wr\n");
    return res;
}
else printf("send ok\n");

res = read(fd, &rcv_val, 1);
if (res < 0){
    printf("Err rd\n");
    return res;
}else printf("rcv_val = 0x%02X\n", rcv_val);

return res;
```

Comment: From the `read(2)` [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read): `"On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately."` This means you should check `errno` or call `perror`.

Comment: I'd suggest checking with `minicom` or similar, to ensure sanity (i.e. that the port can in fact be read from). Also note that you're opening the fd in non blocking mode `O_NDELAY`. The error returned is likely `EAGAIN` (since there probably isn't 1 byte ready when `read` is called).

Comment: Errno corresponds to "Resource temporarily unavailable". Now I look What its mean.

Comment: first, you may test your loopback "cable":
[http://stackoverflow.com/a/19032302/3651540]

Comment: I delete setting O_NDELAY. Now process freezes on read() without any messages.

Comment: Cable its just jumper between Rx, Tx pins on Usb2Serial board.

Comment: Problem is solved by changing usb2serial board. Thanks, dmitriyY.

Comment: Your explanation indicates your using two different ports.  Both ports need to be setup, not just the USB port.  You will need some external hardware to convert between the serial port format and the USB port format.  After the 'write' statement, the var 'res' is being checked, but was not set by the write statement.